# Unable to integrate AliDropship WooCommerce plugin on Siteground/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I recently purchased the AliDropship WooCommerce plugin. When trying to install it on my Siteground-WooCommerce website I get the below errors:

> "Error! ionCube Loader Not found"

and

> "The plugin generated 244 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin."

I deleted and reinstalled but still get the same errors. I also tried with all versions of the plug in i.e ionCube loader version, ionCube loader version for php 7.1 and ionCube loader version for php 7.2+

So far I'm unable to integrate AliDropship WooCommerce plugin on siteground/wordpress cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more poking around I was able to finally resolve it.

For anyone else who may encounter an issue on Siteground

1. Delete the AliDropship WooCommerce Plugin
2. Log into cPanel for your account
3. Go to 1H Software section -> PHP Version Manager
4. Navigate to the directory you would like to change the PHP version (note
   that the change will apply to subdirectories for it as well)
5. Click on the directory name (*public_html*)
6. Select the PHP version 7.0
7. click Save
8. Now download and install the plugin version compatible with PHP 7
9. Finally Activate the plug in

Maybe in the future when there is ionCube for PHP 7.1 - we can upgrade back.

Answer (score 0):

To add to above, I realized I was having issues with deploying the beginner "alids_first_ion.zip" plug in. But when I tried the "Experienced woocommerce users "alidswoo_ion.zip" worked on the first go.

I would advise against using the "Beginner" plugin download.